# Malformed HTML and XPath query

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath, malformed

I have a malformed HTML that I can't change. Running a XPath Query doesn't return the nodes at all:

```
$el = $xpath->query("//a[@class='product']/table"); // can get a tag with "//a[@class='product']"
print_r($el->length); // 0
```

Malformed HTML:

```
<a class="product" href="#">
    <table width="385" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" style="border:1px; border-bottom-color:#E2E2E2; border-bottom-style:solid;">
        <tr>
            <td width="55">
                <img src="http://foobar.com:8080/img/1212.jpg" height="50" width="50">
            </td>
        <td width="195">Cod.27731<br>Product Name</td>
            <td width="60" align="center"><a href="?pageContent=items&price=fab&prodcod=27731">Details</a></td>
            <td width="80" nowrap>
                <div style="color:#FF0000;"><strong>$ 35.23</strong></div>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</a>
```

I can get the a element but I can't get its child (the table)...

Comment: If you do `$document->saveHTML()` you'll notice that DomDocument auto-closes the `<a>` tag before `<table>`.

Comment: will saveHTML() fix malformed HTML?

Comment: I think `loadHTML()` is fixing malformed HTML already (in this case, by closing the a tag)

Comment: saveHTML returns a string but i can't use it to create a new DOMDocument :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since libxml will change the HTML to close the a element before the table, you have to query for the [following-sibling](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) table instead, e.g.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$el = $xpath->query("//a[@class='product']/following-sibling::table");
echo $dom->saveHtml($el->item(0));
```

or traversing from the a element

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$table = $xpath->query("//a[@class='product']")->item(0)->nextSibling;
echo $dom->saveHtml($table);
```

Note that passing an argument to saveHTML [requires at least PHP 5.3.6](http://gooh.posterous.com/the-dom-goodie-in-php-536)

Comment: @thom Yes, when you use `loadHTML` [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html) will try to correct the HTML to some extent to make it parseable. `saveHTML()` will only serialize the DOM tree into HTML markup. An alternative would be to run the broken HTML through [tidy](http://php.net/tidy) before passing it to DOM. This will allow you to influence to some extent how the broken markup gets fixed.